# How to set up ssl certificate on apache server that is running on aws ec2 WIndows server instance?

Tags: laravel, apache, ssl, amazon-ec2, windows-server-2012

I have already set up a DNS record to point my domain to the ec2 instance IP. Next, I don't know how to configure an ssl certificate on Apache that is running on a Windows server. I already have ssl certificate details.

Answer (score 0):

Check out for the conf/httpd.conf in apache that is where you need to edit and add ssl..checkout this link but now you can use letecrypt certificate or any other instead of the one in the link..Or you can use any other the process is the same https://www.entrust.com/knowledgebase/ssl/how-to-configure-an-entrust-ssl-certificate-on-apache-for-windows

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried this and it did not work. Do you have any other ideas?